# Splitting Paragraphs into Sentences - need troubleshooting

Tags: python, list

I have the following chuck of paragraphs that I'm trying to parse into sentences:

```
(['2893357', 'SUPER', 'sesame street. The books are all open. I saw no trash or debris. She was clean and well organized.'], ['2893357', 'STELLAR', '"I stopped and turned it off. He was smiling. He welcomed me to Sewell and asked how he was able to assist me that day.'])
```

My expected result set should be something like:

```
['2893357', 'SUPER', 'sesame street.']
['2893357', 'SUPER', 'The books are all open.']
['2893357', 'SUPER', 'I saw no trash or debris.']
['2893357', 'SUPER', 'She was clean and well organized.']
['2893357', 'STELLAR', '"I stopped and turned it off.']
['2893357', 'STELLAR', '"He was smiling.']
['2893357', 'STELLAR', '"He welcomed me to See and asked how he was able to assist me that day.']
```

The code I have is below:

```
sentences = list(data_set)         
for i,y in enumerate(sentences):
    pig = sentences[i]
    pig = [[pig[0], pig[1], y] for y in pig[2].split('. ')]
    sentences[i:i+1] = pig
```

Thank you.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? How does the produced output differ from your expected output?

Comment: The produced output does not split the paragraphs into sentences.

Comment: The output I get from your code looks exactly like the desired output you describe. Be more specific.

Comment: @user3116753: it does for me, have you tried your sample yourself?

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. Using the example below: data_set = (['2893357', 'SUPER', 'sesame street. The books are all open. I saw no trash or debris. She was clean and well organized.'], ['2893357', 'STELLAR', '"I stopped and turned it off. He was smiling. He welcomed me to Sewell and asked how he was able to assist me that day.']) I don't get the break out like Chirila pointed out using his approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`re.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

```
>>> from re import split
>>> data = (['2893357', 'SUPER', 'sesame street. The books are all open. I saw no trash or debris. She was clean and well organized.'], ['2893357', 'STELLAR', '"I stopped and turned it off.
He was smiling. He welcomed me to Sewell and asked how he was able to assist me that day.'])
>>> new_list = [[w,x,z] for w,x,y in data for z in split("(?<=\.) ", y)]
>>> for item in new_list:
...     print(item)
...
['2893357', 'SUPER', 'sesame street.']
['2893357', 'SUPER', 'The books are all open.']
['2893357', 'SUPER', 'I saw no trash or debris.']
['2893357', 'SUPER', 'She was clean and well organized.']
['2893357', 'STELLAR', '"I stopped and turned it off.']
['2893357', 'STELLAR', 'He was smiling.']
['2893357', 'STELLAR', 'He welcomed me to Sewell and asked how he was able to assist me that day.']
>>>
```

Note however that the output is *slightly* different than the sample output you gave.  I think this is because you made some typos when writing it.  For instance, in the last sentence, you say you want `See`.  However, `See` does not occur in the sample data.  Instead, it should be `Sewell`.

Comment: Regex to split sentences always makes me cringe :/

Comment: Thank you iCodez. Can you please explain the logic?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus - Yea, I'll admit there is usually a better way.  But here, using Regex is pretty efficient.  I can't think of a cleaner solution using Python's string methods.

Comment: Moral of the story: Don't use python's string methods for nlp.

Comment: Ok thanks. Thank you Tyranus. I see the NLTK response. Hmm. This is interesting stuff. Thank you all. Which answer should I accept though.

Comment: @user3116753 - Accept whichever helped you the most or that you think is best.

Comment: I'm accepting iCodez response because it gets the job done. NLTK is the preferred method but I think it might also have it's own nuances.

Answer (score 1):

If you're actually looking to separate sentences you shouldn't use `split`, as it's going to fail on things like exclamation points and abbreviations, and generally there are a lot of edge cases you really don't want to deal with.

Luckily, `nltk` has a utility just for this called `punkt`, which is made to split paragraphs up into sentences. To use `punkt`, just do the following:

```
>>> import nltk.data
>>> text = '''
... Punkt knows that the periods in Mr. Smith and Johann S. Bach
... do not mark sentence boundaries.  And sometimes sentences
... can start with non-capitalized words.  i is a good variable
... name.
... '''
>>> sent_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
>>> print(sent_detector.tokenize(text.strip()))
['Punkt knows that the periods in Mr. Smith and Johann S. Bach do not mark sentence boundaries.',
'And sometimes sentences can start with non-capitalized words.', 
'i is a good variable name.']
```

Example (and many others) borrowed from nltk's [documentation.](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html)

Applied a little more to your specific problem:

```
import nltk.data
sent_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
my_data = ['2893357', 'SUPER', 'sesame street. The books are all open. I saw no trash or debris. She was clean and well organized.']
tokens = sent_detector.tokenize(my_data[2])
print [[my_data[0], my_data[1], sentence] for sentence in tokens]

>>> [['2893357', 'SUPER', 'sesame street.'],
['2893357', 'SUPER', 'The books are all open.'],
['2893357', 'SUPER', 'I saw no trash or debris.'],
['2893357', 'SUPER', 'She was clean and well organized.']]
```

Comment: Thank you Slater. How do I accomplish the above using the NLTK. That seems like that best way to go.

Comment: I get the following error when I use your solution on a larger data set. Would you know what the issue is Mr. Tyranus? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\bestmark_parser_v7.py", line 17, in <module>
    tokens = sent_detector.tokenize(data_set[2])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1217, in tokenize
    return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))

Comment: @user3116753 That is not enough of a traceback to actually debug the problem... Have you installed nltk and downloaded the punkt tokenizer?

Comment: Yes I did. It works perfectly with the smaller example you provided.

Comment: @user3116753 Are you running something different than what is above? Because copying and pasting that into a terminal works perfectly.

Comment: Yes I'm applying your logic to a much larger data set. For the small sample it works perfectly. Any thoughts what might be the issue. I will keep troubleshooting. Thank you.

Comment: @user3116753 If you could post the full traceback I could help... But the portion you posted doesn't even include an error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    tokens = sent_detector.tokenize(data_set[2])
    return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1262, in sentences_from_text
    sents = [text[sl] for sl in self._slices_from_text(text)]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1269, in _slices_from_text
    for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: @user3116753 You have to pass the `tokenize` method a string. Are you just trying to replace my_data with a list of lists?

Comment: Ok I've fixed it let's see if it gives the desired output. thank you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44361/discussion-between-user3116753-and-slater-tyranus)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
>>> data_set = (['2893357', 'SUPER', 'sesame street. The books are all open. I saw no trash or debris. She was clean and well organized.'], ['2893357', 'STELLAR', '"I stopped and turned it off. He was smiling. He welcomed me to Sewell and asked how he was able to assist me that day.'])
>>> for i, j, k in data_set:
...     for sentence in k.split("."):
...             sentence = sentence.strip()
...             if not sentence:
...                     continue
...             print [i, j, sentence + "."]
... 
['2893357', 'SUPER', 'sesame street.']
['2893357', 'SUPER', ' The books are all open.']
['2893357', 'SUPER', ' I saw no trash or debris.']
['2893357', 'SUPER', ' She was clean and well organized.']
['2893357', 'STELLAR', '"I stopped and turned it off.']
['2893357', 'STELLAR', ' He was smiling.']
['2893357', 'STELLAR', ' He welcomed me to Sewell and asked how he was able to assist me that day.']
```

Comment: This just `print`s the objects; I'm sure the OP would like to use them afterwards!

Comment: You are right jonsharpe. I'm going to do a lookup in a dictionary for keywords and get the number of hits. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, collecting the data instead of printing seems easy enough to me :)

Comment: Oh and Chirila. What if I have other sentences enders like exclamation points and question marks?

Comment: Well, you didn't specify that in the question. You should use an regex split like in the other answer. And should be more clear with you questions.

Comment: @user3116753 if you want other sentence enders and a generally more robust solution you should use something more robust, like `nltk`'s `punkt` sentence tokenizer.